# Differences in backslashing between Notepad++ and PHP

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

EDIT: I found a solution I didn't expect. See below.

Using regex via PHP's preg_match_all , I want to match a certain url (EDIT: that is already escaped) in a string formatted as json. The search works wonderfully in Notepad++ (using regex-matching, of course) but `preg_match_all()` just returns an empty array.

Testing on [tryphpregex.com](http://tryphpregex.com/) I found out that somehow my usual approach to escaping a backslash gives a pattern error, i.e. even the simple pattern `https:\\` returns an empty result.

I'm utterly confused and have been trying to debug for too long so I may miss the obvious. Maybe one of you can see the simple error?

[The string.](https://gist.github.com/fridde/b65d3e8109905e44e455)

The pattern (that works fine in Notepad++, but not in PHP):

`%(https:\\/\\/play.spotify.com\\/track\\/)(.*?)(\")%`

Comment: First there are different "flavors" of regexes (that is mentioned in all documentations) and second the way you have to escape depends on how you define your string. That often is the issue, not the regex engine itself. Check what is contained in your strings after you define them.

Comment: @arkascha: note that notepad++ uses the same regex flavor than PHP.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ah, ok. I have no idea about that app, it was a general note. But note yourself that PHP uses different regex flavors because there are different engines. The `preg_...` functions use a single flavor though. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape the slash in PHP `%(https://play.spotify.com/track/)(.*?)(\")%`

The Backslash before doule quote is only needed if you enclosures are double quotes too.

Comment: @fridde: Escaping is not needed because the delimiter is `%` and not the usual `/`

Comment: Actually my quetion was a bit confusing: I was looking for a pattern in the string that ONCE resembled an url, but is coded as a JSON, i.e. already containing escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem.

According to [this site](http://www.developwebsites.net/match-backslash-preg_match-php/), I need to match every backslash with `\\\\`. Horrible, but true.

So my pattern becomes:

`$pattern = "%(https:\\\\/\\\\/play\.spotify\.com\\\\/track\\\\/)(.*?)(\")%";`

Please observe that I tried to find a pattern inside a string that didn't contain clear urls, but urls containing escape characters (it was a json-output from spotify)